# i want to display my result of query like that

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

this is my current result
mysql>select * from city;

### Name   CountryCode District    Population

```
bangaluru   91  bangaluru   6347673
bangaluru   91  bangaluru   347673
bangaluru   91  bangaluru   67673
andhra      91  andhra      63476
mangalore   91  mangalore   63473
```

this is i want :

### Name    CountryCode   District  Population

```
bangaluru   91       bangaluru  6347673
            91       bangaluru  347673
            91       bangaluru  67673
andhra      91       andhra     63476
mangalore   91       mangalore  63473
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN _no = @i THEN '' ELSE @i := _no END
    as row_no,
    _no,
    _name
FROM
(
    SELECT 1 as _no, 'vikas' as _name UNION ALL
    SELECT 1, 'kratika' UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'vikas' 
) t,
(SELECT @i := '') temp
```